# How to catch console-closing event?

Tags: windows, console, windows-vista, subprocess, pipe

The context of my problem is:

1. I have a Windows .NET app (GUI) running as a main process.
2. From this (parent) process, I create a couple of sub-processes as console processes.
3. The main process sends data to the children processes through named pipes.
4. In the main app, I have a list of the sub-processes.

My probleme is that each console has a close ("x") button and can be terminated (whatever the way it is). Since I keep a list of the created consoles in my main app, I would like to know when a console is killed or exited.

My console (child process) program is simply a "main()" with a loop function that reads the pipe (and displays the data). It has no message system or whatever else that could handle a windowing "exit".

The first idea that comes to my head is to poll the sub-processes from the main app to refresh the list. But this means I have to introduce a timer or a thread that watches the consoles. I don't like the idea.

Does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0)` will tell you whether the thread specified in `hThread` argument is signaled and therefore finished. Same goes to `hProcess`.

Both handles of your child process are returned after `CreateProcess()` call. You can either close them immediately, or monitor using `WaitForSingleObject`.